# Bibliography backref on new line with smaller font size

Tags: biblatex, fontsize, back-referencing

At the moment I use

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,dashed=false,
            abbreviate=false,
            natbib=true,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.7\itemsep}
\bibhang=0pt % don't ask, I'm still experimenting ;)
```

which outputs entries like

```
Eddy, Sean R (Nov. 2004). "How do RNA folding algorithms work?" In: Nature
Biotechnology 22.11, pages 1457–1458. ISSN: 1087-0156 (cited on page 1 and 3).
```

But ideally I'd like to have it like

```
Eddy, Sean R (Nov. 2004). "How do RNA folding algorithms work?" In: Nature
Biotechnology 22.11, pages 1457–1458. ISSN: 1087-0156. 
(Cited on pages 1 and 3.)
```

with the backref line in a smaller font size. Note also the big "C" in "Cited" and the different punctuation.

Background info: I think the backref shouldn't be part of the actual main bib information as it's not an info from the article/book/whatever. Of course, the same is true for the "visited on" part but these kind of references (websites) are the exception anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backref=true]{biblatex}

\setlength\bibitemsep{1.7\itemsep}

\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}

\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{%
  \addperiod% NEW
  \iflistundef{pageref}
    {}
%    {\printtext[parens]{% DELETED
    {\newline\footnotesize\printtext[parens]{% NEW
       \ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}
         {\bibstring{backrefpages}\ppspace}
     {\bibstring{backrefpage}\ppspace}%
 %      \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}}% DELETED
       \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}\addperiod}}}% NEW

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Beta},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{A01,B02}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool thanks! :) I like how it automatically knows to start "Cited" in uppercase.

Comment: This is a wonderful solution and exactly what I was looking for. - But it behaves a little bit faulty, at least if being used with biblatex-apa style. `\addperiod` always adds a period - even after additional remarks in parentheses and after URLs where no periods are supposed to be. If I comment out this line the final period vanishes but also from any other bibliography entry where it is needed. How to resolve this?

Comment: @PsychicBirdy Try changing the end `\addperiod}}}` into `\addperiod}}\nopunct}`.